# Oracle dbms_Parallel_execute

Tags: sql, oracle, session, parallel-processing, insert

Suppose I have a table with many millions of rows
and without any indexes

I want to get data from this table
and insert it into another table
by means of `dbms_parallel_execute` package

If I create many chunks , each of size equal to 100000 rows (size doesn't matter)
and decide to run `dbms_parallel_execute.run_task` with `parallel_level = 10`
will Oracle do a SEPARATE full table scan in each and every session
spawned by dbms_parallel_execute?
Or it will reuse one full table scan across the sessions?

If  it will do a SEPARATE full scan - I don't see a profit of use
dbms_parallel_execute. It is better to use
single `INSERT` with `ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML` and `PARALLEL(10)` hints.

So, the question is: will Oracle reuse one full table scan across
multiple `dbms_parallel_execute` sessions or not?

Comment: and why do you want to use this for the job? enable parallel dml, and query, then just insert as select and oracle will do the thing for you.

Comment: gsalem, thanks for response. I intend to use dbms_parallel_execute , because it commits each task separately, so I can view intermediate results.

Comment: I still don't see the advantage, but to answer your question: no, every part of the 'job' will scan a range of rowids, so no full scan by each.

Comment: Sorry for possibly evident question - does rowid range scan is single block reading?

Comment: generally no, they are multiblock, because the rowids are contiguous. But you may happen upon migrated/chained rows that will lead to single block reads.